# Setting array bounds in Python

Tags: python, arrays

How on earth do I set a limitation in an array. All I got is:

```
answerBox = [] * 10 #This will set the array to [ , , , , , , , , ,] storing 10 digits/characters.
```

But in python, I don't know how to tell the code that if an answer (later on) exceeds the 10 digit limit, to print something. But I don't know how... Help?

Comment: you can't. Python operates on the bases that if you have 'n' elements. 'n' is the length and anything outside `n-1` is out of bounds. but you can append elements to it.

Comment: So there is no way of setting an arrays Maximum size?

Comment: well. if you are gonna exceed the programme memory by allocating a ridiculously big size 2929283833939393 something like that, then yeah there is a way. In Python scripts, we simply say "for something in range(1:10):" meaning anything within the range is something I am interested in. this is automatically setting a limit 10 to the range. Other than that, no there is nothing like C++/Java way of `int myArray[10];`

Comment: I want to make a calculator (a simple one) with basic function. And when it is inputted into the array, it shouldn't exceed the array size. Or, do I have to check the length of the answer by using the len() function?

Comment: Check the len of answerBox before you try to add something, if it's 10, don't add and print something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the array size by following code:

```
 >>> data = [None] * 10
 >>> data
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
 >>>
```

Comment: That doesn't work, I tried printing the array size but it wont print out 5 spaces...

Comment: you can see the above output,you will get 5 items for a list

Comment: But when appending to the array, if it's over 5 items, will it display an error or will it just create more space?

Comment: I think you have a version issue, the answer above gives me `[None, None, None, None, None]`. You probably are running something different

Comment: I'm using codecademy.com As I can't get python. So there is no way I can set a limit to an array to 10 items?

Comment: I given the example above, which will set to 10 items,if you want to more then change the no, If you dont want 'none' in the items then replace it with zero.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array of a given size with :

```
a = [ None for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: This is also a way to limit the size of your array.